# Does Microsoft release devices at a special date?

Tags: store

Is there any fixed date when Microsoft introduces its devices? I have in mind a trade fair or other type of event that would be the most probable date.

For me it's important, because I'd need to change my old-ish phone for a new one. And it's either one old Lumia (they are still in the market, somehow), an HP Elite x3, or the Alcatel IDOL 4S. But if a new Andromeda (or whatever) gets released, I'd like to consider it.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no specific dates when Microsoft releases new hardware. Also, there are no dates yet for any Andromeda releases.